# google-admin-sdk push notification expiry

Tags: google-admin-sdk

When watching users events, with google push notifications as outlined here:-

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push

I set the expiry in Unix time milliseconds. It seems to accept it but then on receiving a notification it always sets it to 5 hours in the future.

I setup the expiration by sending in the expiration and unix time in JSON with token etc for the watch, as per the doc.

So is there an internal maximum for the expiry of notifications in admin-sdk. I have read that there maybe on other services. But no clear answers from google docs.

I was hoping to be able to set the expiry to be say 20 years in the future and receive push notifications. Without having to keep setting them up.

Any help would be appreciated with anyone who has done this before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*A notification channel can have an expiration time, with a value determined either by your request or by any Directory API internal limits or defaults (the more restrictive value is used).*" -- was stated in the docs you linked. From there, it is possible that the 5 hours difference that you're seeing every time could be the limit itself. However, there is nothing explicitly mentioned on what the value is. This is probably because that (IMHO) it's possible that the internal limit might be subject for change from time to time.

Comment: Thanks AL for your comment. It just seems very restrictive for a push notification service, to be only valid for 5 hours

Comment: I believe so too. However, I think it's just some kind of safety measure for some reason (not sure on what though, maybe preventing to overuse `watch` on resources that don't change that much?)

Answer (score 0):

So I found [this thread in the Google Issues Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755394) that reported:

> The documentation (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push#making-watch-requests) says that the maximum expiration time is 604800 seconds (1 week) but what we are observing is that anything greater than 6 hours would result in an error.

The date of writing was way back in 2015. If you check the documentation link now, you'll find a note that says:

> **Note**: For the Reports API, the maximum expiration time is 21600 seconds. If you don’t set the expiration property in your request, the expiration time defaults to 21600 seconds after the current time.

This is for the Reports API, however there is a chance that this is probably the same max value for Directory API.

What I could suggest right now is to [file a Feature Request](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/support#missing_features) to be able to set a higher value.

Comment: Thanks AL that is very interesting, I know that's reports. But looks like very similar behaviour. This disappointing bit, is on the reports issue. Its not been touched since 28 September 2015. Thanks for the file a Feature Request. I will take a look, and raise one

Comment: You're welcome Aubrey. Do share if you managed to send a Feature Request, and if ever they share details about the behavior. Cheers! :)

Comment: Feature Request raised. Hope I have done it correctly. I included more information in it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38150559

Comment: I have raised the feature request and no one from Google seems to have looked at it (As far as I can tell). I wonder how long it takes, before gaining an answer. If anyone who looks at this bug could star it, that may help it. It currently has 3 stars

Comment: I'm not sure what the process for Feature request is in Google. I'm sure I'm one of the ones that starred it. :)

Comment: Thanks AL It is appreciated :)

Comment: From latest testing, seems like the maximum amount of time to watch the users is 48 hours. I didn't find any documentation for it